# Firebase Hosting Failed to load module script

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, hosting, vite

Error: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I have a Vite / React / TypeScript app which I'm trying to host on Firebase. I am getting the error above when I run firebase deploy. I tried putting the index.html in public folder, and it looks like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Fitness App</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Tried putting index.html in public folder ( caused an error on npm run build )
Tried changing the path to ../src/main.tsx ( no difference )

Comment: I figured out the problem. For anyone who comes across this in the future, you need to change your "public" key in firebase.json to point at "dist" instead of "public".